# не работает include

Tags: php, html, css

файл который нужен находиться в папке "block" а файл в котором он нужен находиться "pages/main".
Я указал путь таким образом  пробовал менять путь и добавлял "../",
но все без толку, выдает ошибку ссылая на строку с указанным путем. Warning: include(blocks/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\mysite\pages\main\all.php on line 20.

Comment: лучше полную структуру от корня напишите. возможно надо `../../`

Comment: прошу прощения, в папке "blocks"

Comment: вроде `../../blocks/header.php`, если `blocks` находится в корне

Comment: да, файл находиться там

Comment: но ../../ не помогло

Comment: теперь стили не работают)

Comment: значит теперь проблема в пути у стилей)

Comment: спасибо за помощь)